# Image groups in db based on product or news item

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, dynamic

Currently working on a bespoke ecommerce application using Codeigniter.

I have a products table with a list of products and a news table with a list of news items.

For example, the news items are displayed dynamically using a foreach loop, i would like to add images to the news items dynamically though some news items have 2 or 3 images.

I understand i could use an image_id to match the news item/product to an image within a table (url links of images), but what about multiple images, is it a fie
ld type? a different database setup?

News.php

```
<a href="news/<?php echo $news_item['slug'] ?>
<h2><?php echo $news_item['title'] ?></h2>
</a>
<div id="main">
    <?php echo $news_item['text'] ?>
</div>
<a href="news/<?php echo $news_item['image'] ?>">

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: yes i think you need to setup the different table where image_id and the associated news_item_id is their. and news_item_id relate to the main news_table id.

Comment: im looking for multiple images not the database table schema for news thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could serialize an array of images (containing urls of images) for each news into a JSON string and input it into the image field in your news table.

See it here: [Serialize function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

Will that work for you?